# Keep on getting error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable

Tags: c++

I am trying to help a friend of mine with his coding but we both get the same error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error
```

I'm new on C++ and just finished learning about loops in my class so this is all really new to me and I tried to research on my own but I had trouble trying to find anything. I would appreciate any guidance/help on this.

```
    // ConsoleApplication8.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;

    enum daysPerMonth {

            JAN = 31, FEB = 28, MAR = 31,

            APR = 30, MAY = 31, JUN = 30,

            JUL = 31, AUG = 31, SEP = 30,

            OCT = 31, NOV = 30, DEC = 31
        };

void homeworkHeader(string title){
            cout << "Ticket : \n";
            cout << "Course : \n";
            cout << "Intructor : \n";
            cout << "Student : \n";
            cout << "Environment : Windows 10/Visual Studio 2019\n";
        }
        int input(int day, int month, int year){
        cout << "Enter the number that is in the day's place : ";
        cin >> day;
        cout << "Enter the number that is in the month's place : ";
        cin >> month;
        cout << "Enter the number that is in the year's place : ";
        cin >> year;
        return 0;
        }
        int getDaysBeforeThisMonth(int month){
            int numDays = 0;
            switch (month){
            case (12):
                numDays += NOV;
            case (11):
                numDays += OCT;
            case (10):
                numDays += SEP;
            case (9):
                numDays += AUG;
            case (8):
                numDays += JUL;
            case (7):
                numDays += JUN;
            case (6):
                numDays += MAY;
            case (5):
                numDays += APR;
            case (4):
                numDays += MAR;
            case (3):
                numDays += FEB;
            case (2):
                numDays += JAN;
            case (1):
                numDays += 0;
            }
            return numDays;
        }
int addLeapYearDay(int year, int month){
        if (month >= 3){
            if ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int daysIntoYear(int day, int month, int year) {
        int numDays = 0;
        numDays = getDaysBeforeThisMonth(month);
        numDays += day;
        numDays += addLeapYearDay(year, month);
        cout << numDays;
        return numDays;
    }
```

Comment: This error means that `ld` needs to know a function, named `main`, as the entry point of your program, but it can not find such a function.

Answer (score 0):

Every C++ program needs a function called `main`. It's where the program starts.

In the code you've written where do you think the program will start? It's not obvious to me.